# создать функцию которая складывает значения элементов

Tags: javascript

```
function sumArray() {

    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        arr3.push(arr1[i] + arr2[i])
    }
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr3 = []
console.log(sumArray(arr3))
```

Что не так, почему мне не складывает 2 массива? Нужно через цикл.

создать функцию которая складывает значения элементов с одинаковыми индексами и возвращает новый результирующий массив.

```
 **EXAMPLE:
 [1,2,3,4]
     [2,3,4,5]
 результат
   [3,5,7,9]**
```

Comment: все у вас складывает. вы результат не возвращаете просто

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы ничего не возвращаете из своей функции. Массивы складываются, но третий массив просто не выводится, так как функция его не возвращает.
2. Обычно функция не должна оперировать с внешними переменными, она должна получать значения в аргументах и возвращать новое значение.

Попробуйте так:

```js
function sumArray(array1, array2) {
    let array3 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        array3.push(array1[i] + array2[i]);
    }
    return array3;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(sumArray(arr1, arr2));
```

Comment: а когда нужно что то возврощать через return ?

Comment: Когда вам нужен результат работы функции вне самой функции.

Comment: Формально ваш код тоже рабочий, вам оставалось только вывести измененную в функции внншнюю переменную вместо отсутствующего результата функции. Однако писать функции, которые берут данные из внешних переменных и меняют внешние переменные, не советуют - при таком подходе возрастает опасность ошибок.

Answer (score 3):

Немного дополню ответ [@vsemozhebuty](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/321883/vsemozhebuty)

Учитывая нынешнюю реализацию, если в первом массиве будет больше эл-тов чем во втором - получите массив с NaN'ами (будут складываться числа с первого + undefined со второго = Not a Number).

Как минимум, можно просто добавить проверку - если undefined то суммируем ноль.

```js
function sumArray(array1, array2) {
  let array3 = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array3.push( (array1[i] || 0) + (array2[i] || 0) );
  }
  return array3;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(sumArray(arr1, arr2));
```

Так же, касательно длины массива:

А почему вы смотрите только на длину первого массива?
Не лучше ли будет брать max/min длину и возвращать массив равный ей?

```js
function sumArray(array1, array2) {
  let array3 = [], 
      len = Math.max(array1.length, array2.length); // или Math.max(...)
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    array3.push( (array1[i] || 0) + (array2[i] || 0) );
  }
  return array3;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 0, 3];

console.log(sumArray(arr1, arr2));
```

И, добавлю вариант с любым кол-вом массивов, но без цикла for:

```js
function sumArray(...arrays) {
  let max = arrays.reduce((e, n) => Math.max(e, n.length), 0);
  return Array.from({length: max}).map((i, idx) => arrays.reduce((sum, curr) => sum + (curr[idx] || 0), 0));
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr11 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9];
let arr22 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(sumArray(arr1, arr2, arr11, arr22));
```

И, тоже вариант для любого кол-ва массивов, но уже используя цикл for:

```js
function sumArray(...arrays) {
  let arr = [];
  let max = Math.max(...arrays.map(e => e.length));
  for ( let a = 0; a < max; a++ ) {
    sum = 0;
    for ( let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++ ) {
      sum += arrays[i][a] || 0;
    }
    arr.push(sum);
  }
  return arr;
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9];
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr11 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9];

console.log(sumArray(arr1, arr2, arr11));
```